# After i send the reset password in email how do i get the text in the Link - php

Tags: php

What I'm trying to do is to get the text in the link that i inputted after sending the email. Something like this.

```
$ForgotID = 'DN6ZPzA6247yWhHaFbXi';

$messageBody = '<a href="https://******.com/ResetPasswordForm.php?id='.$ForgotID.'">Click here to change your password.</a>';
```

Then when the user click the link it will redirect to the link given then how do i get the `id='_____________________'`? So that, that is my way to search the specific row in database before i update the password. How i do this? Thanks Guys.

Comment: Using `$_GET['id']` perhaps?

Comment: Since this question basically is about PHP 101, I would recommend you to go through some basic PHP tutorials. You will run into plenty of questions otherwise. You should also start by doing some extensive research when you actually run into an issue before posting.

Comment: Could you please explain this: "when the user click the link it will redirect to the link given"? Does it mean that script `https://******.com/ResetPasswordForm.php` perform redirect from php code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**E-Mail Msg:**

```
<?php

$ForgotID = 'DN6ZPzA6247yWhHaFbXi';

$messageBody = '<a href="https://******.com/ResetPasswordForm.php?id='.$ForgotID.'">Click here to change your password.</a>';

?>
```

**ResetPasswordForm.php** ( On `ResetPasswordForm.php` )

```
//On Click On Mail Verification Link 
//Browser Url:  https://******.com/ResetPasswordForm.php?id=DN6ZPzA6247yWhHaFbXi

<?php 

$id = $_GET['id'];

//Now After Get This $id Here, Check In Your Table in Verification_code Column , 
//Where its found ! and if Found Then Take Email Id And Change the Password and Update it,
//And if Not Found Then Display the message token mismatch. 

?>
```